# Dynamic data assignment doesn't work on Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have this code, it loops through the `this.product.taxons` and for each element, it looks through the array of objects `this.taxons` to find the `taxon` with the same value.

```
this.product.taxons.forEach((taxon) => {
    // taxon = 'bed_sheet'
    const data = this.taxons.find((x) => x.value === exclusion);
    // data = {
    //   value: 'bed_sheet',
    //   model: 'bedSheet'
    // }
    this.currentProduct.`${data.model}` = true; // this does not work.
  });
```

but my problem is that `this.currentProduct.'${data.model}' = true;` which is translated to `this.currentProduct.bedSheet = true;`

and returns an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`
any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using brackets. 

this.currentProduct[yourField] = true

Comment: @Erenn ooohhhh just like a normal object. why I didn't think about that! thanks!

Comment: @Terry Yes!!! thank you!